# Setting different struct members equal to each other

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Suppose I have two structs of different types
EX:

```
 typedef struct struct_A
 {
        int member_A1
        char member_A2
 }STRUCT_A;

typedef struct struct_B
 {
        int member_B1
        char member_B2
 }STRUCT_B;
```

and then they're initialized as followed

```
 void struct_A_init(STRUCT_A *struct_A_pointer)
 {
       int i;
       for(i=0; i<=10; i++)
       {
           struct_A_pointer[i].member_A1;
           struct_A_pointer[i].member_A2;
       }

 }

 void struct_B_init(STRUCT_B *struct_B_pointer)
 {
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<=10; i++)
      {
           struct_B_pointer[i].member_B1;
           struct_B_pointer[i].member_B2;
      }

 }
```

and then defined globally and used as followed

```
   STRUCT_A struct_A_pointer[10];
   STRUCT_B struct_b_pointer[10];

some_function(types, types, types)
{
     struct_A_pointer[0].member_A1 = struct_B_pointer[7].member_B1;
}
```

why wouldn't this work if the members are of the same type?
Currently I have this same set up, and I load values into struct_B_pointer[7].memberB1, and when I set that equal to struct_A_pointer[0].member_A1 it only receives a value of 0. not what is actually in struct_B_pointer, and I don't know why this would happen if the members are of the same type. Additionally, I've also tried creating a dummy variable and tried the following

```
  dummy_Var = struct_B_pointer[7].member_B1;

  struct_A_pointer[0].member_A1 = dummy_Var;
```

but I receive the same results, kinda thought I could trick they system with this one :p

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Show an entire program that displays the problem.

Comment: its too long to post the whole thing, that's what I tried originally, I got told that there's too much code, and not enough of my own words

Comment: Your last edit did not add any value. The abstract example was ok so far. I rolled back your last edit therefore.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 for(i=0; i<=10; i++)
  {
       struct_B_pointer[i].member_B1;
       struct_B_pointer[i].member_B2;
  }
```

does not initialise nothing. In fact the whole loop is a NOOP, which finally mostly likely provokes undefined behaviour by accessing the 11th element, which is one past the array.

You want to loop over 10 elements only and assign something to the members

```
 for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
       struct_B_pointer[i].member_B1 = 42;
       struct_B_pointer[i].member_B2 = 43;
  }
```

More over you do not need to explicitly initialise the arrays (to zero) at all, because the compiler does this for you, as they are defined global.

Comment: I see that, but they're given new values regardless in the code

Comment: @user6130096: You might want to use a debugger stepping through the code while inspecting the relevant variables at the different stages of execution.

Comment: @user6130096: Also just remove all those invocations of UB due to indexing the arrays out of bounds. After UB had been invoked you cannot trust the program any more. Everything could happen from then on.

Comment: i'm not sure I know what you mean by UB?

Comment: UB = Undefined Behaviour @user6130096